# making a mass texting app with keywords

Tags: android, sms

I'm on a youtube channel trying to follow a 200 lesson series on Android development when all I want to know first is if my app idea is possible.

I want to make an app for mass texting to a small group probably under 100 people at any given time.

I don't need any of that short code stuff, actually I'd like to use my GV# since that's a free long code.

Right now what I do is I use GV & the Gmail workaround (if you don't know what that is you can ask me or google it) but it is a long and tedious process due to the fluctuation of subscribers.

**My question is**:

I need the keywords capability too, which GV does not provide which
led me to think about making an app. I would also like to have people
added to the list automatically via keyword. I will be sending out
10-20 or so bursts a month from my AT&T Samsung Galaxy S II.

I'm obviously getting pretty desperate... any help, questions, or advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
  SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
  String number = "8001234567";
  sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, "Enter text message here", null, null);
```

and remember to set your permissions in the manifest to

```
  android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
```

that should get you started in the correct direction.

Comment: I have no idea what that means. I haven't made an app before or started actually making it. Does your comment mean that it's posible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but your going to need a lot more than just code .... your going to need to download all of the necessary tools to develop the app like Eclipse, Android SDK, Java Jdk ... you got a long way to go but those 200 lessons will get you there I promise!

Comment: Yeah I have all the tools. I'm following this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A can you at least tell me the videos to pay the most attention to when I get around to them?

Comment: If your work bench is set up all you have to do to send 1 single text message is this    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
     // here is where the destination of the text should go
     String number = "8001234567";
     sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, "Hello", null, null);
    }
}

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. But will it have the feature 'keywords' like those texting services online? protexting for example.

Comment: You can build anything you see ... If some other app does what you want the process can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need an Android app to send SMS. You can use some web based APIs too.

There are some companies like Twilio, Tropo and MediaBurst that provide web based APIs that you could call from a web service or from an Android app.

There are also some operators offering web based APIs for sending SMS through their network using a web based API including Bluevia (see https://bluevia.com).

So equally you could just write a web service if that is easier for you.

Comment: yeah because right now I'm looking at those payed monthly services like ProTexting or Tatango... but I can't pay for those right now. If those Web based API's could use a long code that is NOT my personal phone number, via something like Google Voice and their long code phone number that would be great. It's just so tedious to have them text their name, add them to Gmail via the unique GV email associated and assigned to their number and my account, and then sending out texts via Gmail to bypass google voices 5 text limit.

Comment: Really if they could add themselves with a keyword functionality that would be fantastic. But I'm not sure if a web based API could do that, if so then it looks like that Bluevia site could supply me the utilities and info to do it and make an app to do it off my phone too.

Comment: Also it has to be free to make and use.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app on the market called SMS KeyWords. Sounds like what your looking for.